Complex SQLAlchemy relationships where external variables affect the result
I'd like to understand the correct or recommended way to implement a relationship() in SQLAlchemy, where the foreign row depends on query and that query uses some external variable.
The specific example - code below - is where an object has a responsible user, and that user changes based on time. I do not want to simply amend the user table - i want the ability to 'time travel' and show who was or will be responsible, based on some external variable.
I'm unsure of hybrid_properties are the way to go. I would be accept a secondary/join table (type_id, from, to) if that is more 'correct', in fact for purposes of data management that would be better i think. The main question I have is how to correct model such variability in SQLAlchemy ORM.
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, Session, DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, between, create_engine

engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=False)

dt = datetime(2002, 1, 1).date()


def get_session_time():
    return dt


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "people"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    username: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    valid_from: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(server_default="2000-01-01")
    valid_to: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(server_default="9999-12-31")


class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = "nodes"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    responsible: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("people.username"))

    @hybrid_property
    def responsible_user(self):
        with Session(engine) as session:
            return (
                session.query(Person)
                .filter(
                    Person.username == self.responsible,
                    between(get_session_time(), Person.valid_from, Person.valid_to),
                )
                .one_or_none()
            )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"node=({self.id},{self.responsible_user.id})"


Node.metadata.create_all(engine)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"\nDate={get_session_time()}")
    with Session(engine) as s:
        p1 = Person(username="user1", valid_to=datetime(2010, 12, 31))
        p2 = Person(username="user1", valid_from=datetime(2011, 1, 1))
        p3 = Person(username="user2")

        n1 = Node(responsible="user1")
        n2 = Node(responsible="user2")

        s.add_all([p1, p2, p3, n1, n2])
        s.commit()

        print(n1,n2)

    dt = datetime(2030, 1, 1).date()
    print(f"\nDate={get_session_time()}")

    with Session(engine) as s:
        n1 = s.query(Node).filter(Node.id == "1").one_or_none()
        n2 = s.query(Node).filter(Node.id == "2").one_or_none()
        print(n1,n2)

